# SQL statement to delete from two rows if multiple conditions match

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete from `invitations`, where the column `invited_at` is older than three days. Additionally, the column `role` of the table `users` must have the value `1`, `2` or `3`. The value of `user_id` of the table `invitations` and `users` must match. If this matches, the row of the table `users` and the row of the table `invitations` should be deleted. This is my sql statement:

```
DELETE FROM invitations AS inv, users AS us
WHERE inv.user_id = us.user_id
AND us.role = 0 OR 2 OR 3
AND inv.invited_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
```

I somehow can't get it working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the syntax you are aiming for:

```
DELETE i
    FROM invitations i JOIN
         users u
         ON i.user_id = u.user_id
    WHERE u.role IN (1, 2, 3) AND
          i.invited_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would like to add something to my statement. If I only want to delete the rows, where 'user_id' is NOT listed in the table 'users_clients', how must the syntax look then? Thanks!

Comment: @LeonardNiehaus . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not in comments.